# Comparação de duas datas usando o tipo varchar MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query

estou com um dúvida em relação a elaboração de uma consulta SQL em que eu passo um data de cadastro e verifico se é maior que a data atual, mas tenho um probleminha a data de cadastro é varchar e segue o formato "dd/mm/aaaa", segue abaixo a o select:

```
SELECT * FROM Evento 
WHERE data_evento > curdate()
ORDER BY idEvento ASC LIMIT 0,3;
```

Comment: O formato das data são diferentes e o tipo deve ser date/datetime para evitar outros problemas. O ideal é arrumar isso em uma nova coluna se não possível o quebra ganho é conveter data (varchar)  para date.

Comment: @rray obrigado pela dica, eu até sei que não é correto mas infelizmente não posso alterar, com certeza mudando o formato funcionaria perfeitamente, mas será que isso não é possivél?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converta o campo para data no próprio `SELECT` usando a função `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
SELECT * FROM Evento 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(data_evento, "%d/%m/%Y") > curdate()
ORDER BY idEvento ASC LIMIT 0,3;
```

Comment: Obrigado Roberto, funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for CAST:
CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )
Syntax for CONVERT:
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )